# Json Multidimensional para Object em C#

Tags: c#, json

Estou aprendendo c# e estou tendo uma certa dificuldade de passar um json multidimensional para object fazendo um deserialize. Não sei muito bem como resolver isso.

Veja meu json

```
string json2 = @"[
                            {
                                        firstName: ""joao"",
                                        lastName: ""silva"",
                                        dateOfBirth:
                                                     {
                                                        year: ""1990"",
                                                        month: ""01"",
                                                        day: ""01""
                                                     }
                            },
                            {
                                        firstName: ""carla"",
                                        lastName: ""dias"",
                                        dateOfBirth:
                                                     {
                                                        year: ""2000"",
                                                        month: ""02"",
                                                        day: ""02""
                                                    }
                            }
                         ]";
```

agora as classes que eu criei(na verdade foi o c# com paste especial)

```
  public class Class1
    {
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
        public Dateofbirth dateOfBirth { get; set; }
    }


    public class Dateofbirth
    {
        public string year { get; set; }
        public string month { get; set; }
        public string day { get; set; }
    }

    public class Rootobject
    {
        public Class1[] Property1 { get; set; }
    }
```

Agora eu tentando fazer o deserialize

```
 List<Rootobject> listLad = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Rootobject>>(json2);

Response.Write(listLad[0].Property1[0].lastName);
```

porem dá erro (estou muito acostumado com php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você andou lá perto.
Apenas necessita das classes *Class1* e *Dateofbirth*.

O que esse *json* representa é uma lista de objectos que podem ser representados pela *Class1*, assim não é necessária a classe *Rootobject*

Desserialize assim:

```
List<Class1> listLad = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Class1>>(json2);
```

**Nota:**

Não sei porque o Visual Studio gera a outra classe, talvez considere que o json, para estar bem formatado, deveria ser assim:

```
{
    Property1:[
        {
                    firstName: ""joao"",
                    lastName: ""silva"",
                    dateOfBirth:
                                 {
                                    year: ""1990"",
                                    month: ""01"",
                                    day: ""01""
                                 }
        },
        {
                    firstName: ""carla"",
                    lastName: ""dias"",
                    dateOfBirth:
                                 {
                                    year: ""2000"",
                                    month: ""02"",
                                    day: ""02""
                                }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Funcionou amigo. Mas eu não entendi o por que então do c# ter criado o RootObject. você saberia me dizer.

Comment: Não tenho a certeza, talvez porque, apesar de no json não estar declarado, existe um "RootObject" (Classe1[]), ou pelo menos deveria existir: o json deveria ser assim: `{root:[ ... ]}` Se usar o [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) ele só gera as duas classes.

Answer (score -1):

Use `fastJSON [^] ' s Parse ( )` método que lhe dará `Dictionary <string , object>` representação do JSON que você pode atravessar.

Comment: Pelo que eu li o fastJson ele faz a conversão para Dictionary sem a ver uma necessidade de uma classe que represente aquele json. É isso?